# Voltage doubler - common ground for MOSFET?

Tags: power-supply

I have a transformer putting out 24VAC, which I then rectify to drive some solenoids using mosfets.  Some of my solenoids need higher voltage though, so I've constructed a voltage doubler:
[image]

However, I'm not sure how a common ground will work here..  My mosfets are controlled via 5V, which has a common ground with the 24VDC, so they can be controlled fine.  But technically that same ground is in the middle of C1+C2 of the doubler, I think?  So I'm not sure I can tie the 50VDC ground (- of C2) to the same ground as the 24VDC ground... Or am I overcomplicating things and that will be fine?  I get how the doubler works, in theory, and how rectifying AC gives you a ground, in theory, but not well enough to see how they all connect together...

Comment: If I understood you corrrectly, no you are not overcomplicating things. It is a very real concern. Connecting the two grounds together would create a short across the diodes during some part of the cycle and cause things to not operate as you wish. Not sure what you can really do about it though. A 1:1 transformer to float your charge pump would do it but then you might as well go with a 1:2 transformer and rectify that.

Comment: Your new GND is moved to C2-. what is max Vgs?  Is 5V enuf? is C big enough to be practical? Have you thought about ripple noise? What is L/R?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 the circuit driving the mosfet needs to be on the 5V from the original 25V ground, is the issue

Comment: That won’t work is Source is -24vdc and gat is 0 to 5

Comment: _"mosfet needs to be on the 5V from the **original** 25V ground"_ - what was the original power supply circuit, and what did you add or change to make it look like the schematic in your question?

Comment: @BruceAbbott the 24VAC is feeding both a straight rectifier for 25VDC and the schematic in question.  I also have a separate 5V supply with its ground hooked to the 25VDC ground